# Date value loaded once with Django QuerySet filtered on date.today

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

Scenario: a queryset filtered by a date value seems to use a date value as generated by the process once and then reused for all subsequent requests. That is, if the app is running for a few days, and a piece of content is published with the publish date equal to the current day, it will *not* show up as published until the application server is reloaded.

The obvious answer is that the queryset is using `date.today()` instead of `date.today`, however that's not the case here:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from django.db import models

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_query_set().filter(
                published_date__lte=date.today, active=True)
```

Why is `date.today` not being evaluated properly? Am I missing something *blindingly obvious* here or is there something else going on?

This is an app running Django 1.4.16 on Python 2.7 with Apache mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method:

```
date.today()
```

`date.today` just returns the built-in method. It doesn't actually call it. Example:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.today
<built-in method today of type object at 0x97f780>
>>> date.today()
datetime.date(2014, 11, 4)
```

Comment: This may end up being the issue, but not for the explanation stated. True, the statement `date.today` does not call the function. However when provided as a queryset lookup argument, the callable is executed at query time.